# Choosing random text file from directory and reading from it c#

Tags: c#, text-files

I'm currently trying to create a program that can choose a text file at random from a directory, and then read specific lines from that text file and output them into variables. The problem is I have no idea how to go about this, as I'm relatively new to c#.

I would greatly appreciate any help with this issue.

Comment: Please note your effort. What did you try to do so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
Random rand = new Random();
List<string> files = Directory.GetFiles("C:/").Where(F => F.ToLower().EndsWith(".txt")).ToList();
string text = File.ReadAllText(files[rand.Next(0, files.Count)]);
string[] lines = text.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string result = lines[0]; // or each number you want.
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into System.IO. Here's an example to get you started:

```
string path = @"C:\Temp\txt";
Random rand = new Random();

// pick a random file
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
string randomFile = files[rand.Next(files.Length)];
```

The code will pick a file at random from the path provided. Note that I don't restrict that to text files (check out the overloaded options for the `GetFiles` method). I'll leave it up to you to do the very same thing for the text lines.